# How to remove the columns which contains NA in linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I would like to remove the column which contains any number of NA. I used this command

`awk ' $0 !="NA" {print $0}' file`

But it does not work.
For example, the file is as following

```
1  2 3 NA  6  male
4  6 2 1   NA female
NA 2 2 NA  3  male
7  2 2 7   NA male
```

I want to the output file as

```
  2 3 male
  6 2 female
  2 2 male
  2 2 male
```

Comment: Please can you add a sample of your input and the desired output to make it clearer what you're trying to do?

Comment: What is the content of the file？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make two passes over the data. The first pass should save all the input in an array, find the column numbers that contain `NA`, and save that in another array. Then at the end you print all the saved data, but skip over the columns that are in the second array.

```
awk '{ lines[NR] = $0; for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if ($i == "NA") skip[i] = 1;}
     END { for (i = 1; i <= NR; i++) {
            nf = split(lines[i], fields);
            for (j = 1; j <= nf; j++) if (!(j in skip)) printf("%s ", fields[j]);
            printf("\n");
           } 
         }' inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: I do not know where I should input file.

Comment: The input file is the next argument.